# Primefaces <p:chart> not being properly shown

Tags: jsf, charts, primefaces

I am trying to build a date chart based on [this](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chart/date.xhtml) example:

.xhtml:

```
<p:chart id="graficoVendasPorPeriodo" type="line" model="#{relatorioVendaMB.vendasPorPeriodo}"/>
```

.java:

```
private void constroiVendasPorPeriodo(Date dataInicio, Date dataFim) {
    List<Object[]> vendasPeriodo = ControleVenda.listarQtdeVendasPorPeriodo(dataInicio, dataFim);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

    vendasPorPeriodo = new LineChartModel();

    LineChartSeries lcs = new LineChartSeries();
    lcs.setLabel("Vendas Por Período");
    int max = 0;

    for (Object[] obj : vendasPeriodo) {
        int i = ((BigInteger) obj[1]).intValue();
        lcs.set(obj[0], i);

        if (i >= max) {
            max = i;
        }
    }

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(dataFim);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + 1);
    dataFim = calendar.getTime();

    calendar.setTime(dataInicio);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - 1);
    dataInicio = calendar.getTime();

    vendasPorPeriodo.addSeries(lcs);

    vendasPorPeriodo.setTitle("Vendas por período");
    vendasPorPeriodo.setZoom(true);

    Axis yAxis = vendasPorPeriodo.getAxis(AxisType.Y);
    yAxis.setLabel("Vendas");
    yAxis.setMax(max+10);
    yAxis.setMin(0);

    DateAxis xAxis = new DateAxis("Período");
    xAxis.setTickAngle(-50);
    xAxis.setMin(sdf.format(dataInicio));
    xAxis.setMax(sdf.format(dataFim));
    xAxis.setTickFormat("%#d-%m-%Y");

    System.out.println("Período: " + sdf.format(dataInicio) + ", " + sdf.format(dataFim));

    vendasPorPeriodo.getAxes().put(AxisType.X, xAxis);
}// this method is being called in the '@PostConstruct' method
```

The `listarQtdeVendasPorPeriodo(dataInicio, dataFim)` method returns a `List<Object[]>` where each 'Object[]' array contains, on the first position, a String and, on the second position, an int.

The problem is that, when I execute the code, absolutely nothing is being displayed, not even an empty chart or an exception. Could someone point my mistake and help me fix this problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: I think your code provided is incomplete. I don’t see in your Java code the getter/setter for vendasPeriosa?  Can you provide more of your example?  Also what scope if your bean?

Comment: @Melloware, I've properly created the getter and setter for ´vendasPorPeriodo´, and the ManagedBean is "View Scoped".

Comment: Ok good. Next are their any JavaScript errors in the console?

Comment: How about What PrimeFaces and JSF version you are using also?  Have you tried to create a simple p:chart example and get it to show up on your page?

Comment: Well, I've never noticed that before, but yes. There is the following error being thrown on my console: "TypeError: this.proxy.getTime is not a function". Also, I'm using Primefaces 6.1 and JSF 2.2

Comment: @Melloware, I also tried the example on [this](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chart/date.xhtml) link and it worked normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is the underlying Jqplot that Primefaces uses your date format is incorrect.  See this answer: [jqplot: "this.proxy.getTime is not a function" / date input parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6689993/jqplot-this-proxy-gettime-is-not-a-function-date-input-parser)

Comment: Awesome!   Glad that was helpful.